# Apache Spark: setting executor instances does not change the executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have an Apache Spark application running on a YARN cluster (spark has 3 nodes on this cluster) on cluster mode.

When the application is running the Spark-UI shows that 2 executors (each running on a different node) and the driver are running on the third node.
I want the application to use more executors so I tried adding the argument --num-executors to Spark-submit and set it to 6.

`spark-submit --driver-memory 3G --num-executors 6 --class main.Application --executor-memory 11G --master yarn-cluster myJar.jar <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> ...`

However, the number of executors remains 2.

On spark UI I can see that the parameter spark.executor.instances is 6, just as I intended, and somehow there are still only 2 executors.

I even tried setting this parameter from the code

```
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.instances", "6")
```

Again, I can see that the parameter was set to 6, but still there are only 2 executors.

Does anyone know why I couldn't increase the number of my executors?

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is 12g in yarn-site.xml

Comment: what is value of yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb in yarn-site.xml??

Comment: Yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is 12GiB

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Increase `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` in `yarn-site.xml`

With 12g per node you can only launch driver(3g) and 2 executors(11g).

Node1 - driver 3g (+7% overhead)

Node2 - executor1 11g (+7% overhead)

Node3 - executor2 11g (+7% overhead)

now you are requesting for executor3 of 11g and no node has 11g memory available.

for 7% overhead refer spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead and spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: I couldn't increase this parameter because I don't have enough RAM, but I tried it on a different spark application that does not need that much executor memory and it worked, thanks

Comment: I have been agonizing over a similar issue for a few days. Thank you for your answer, worked like a charm!

Comment: Is the 7% fixed? Any way we can adjust 7% overhead? I could see the settings but its not telling the % value instead 384?

Comment: @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru yes you can change it, spark 2.3 onwards these properties are known as spark.executor.memoryOverhead  spark.driver.memoryOverhead and their default value is 10%, you can set absolute value to change them. Refer:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @banjara, I have not set the executor-memory(its default:1GB), passing num-executors is not honored with spark-submit. I've got 70GB memory in the yarn

Answer (score 16):

Note that `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is ***total*** memory that a ***single*** NodeManager can allocate across ***all*** containers on one node.

In your case, since `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 12G`, if you add up the memory allocated to all YARN containers on any single node, it cannot exceed 12G.

You have requested 11G (`-executor-memory 11G`) for ***each*** Spark Executor container. Though 11G is less than 12G, this still won't work. Why ?

- Because you have to account for `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`, which is `min(executorMemory * 0.10, 384)` (by *default*, unless you  override it).

So, following math must hold true:

*`spark.executor.memory` + `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` **<=** `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`*

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html for latest documentation on `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`

Moreover, `spark.executor.instances` is **merely a request**. Spark ApplicationMaster for your application will make a request to YARN ResourceManager for number of containers = `spark.executor.instances`. Request will be granted by ResourceManager on NodeManager node based on:

- Resource availability on the node. YARN scheduling has its own nuances - [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/) is a good primer on how YARN FairScheduler works.
- Whether `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` threshold has not been exceeded on the node:

  - (number of spark containers running on the node  * (`spark.executor.memory` + `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`)) **<=** `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`*

If the request is not granted, **request will be queued** and granted when above conditions are met.

Answer (score 4):

To utilize the spark cluster to its full capacity you need to set values for `--num-executors`, `--executor-cores` and `--executor-memory` as per your cluster:

- `--num-executors` command-line flag or `spark.executor.instances` configuration property controls the number of executors requested ;
- `--executor-cores` command-line flag or `spark.executor.cores` configuration property controls the number of concurrent tasks an executor can run ;
- `--executor-memory` command-line flag or `spark.executor.memory` configuration property controls the heap size.

Answer (score 2):

You only have 3 nodes in the cluster, and one will be used as the driver, you have only 2 nodes left, how can you create 6 executors?

I think you confused `--num-executors` with `--executor-cores`.

To increase concurrency, you need more cores, you want to utilize all the CPUs in your cluster.

Comment: So there can be only one executor per node?

Comment: no, you have 12g memory available per node and one executor is taking 11g, so you can't launch second executor on same node. you can increase  yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb or reduce --executor-memory to launch multiple executors on same node